# What is returned by Open::URI.open?

Tags: ruby, open-uri

I cannot tell from the rdoc for Open::URI what is returned when I do:

```
result = open(url)
```

The URL returns XML, but how do I see/parse the XML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`open` returns an IO object.  You can do something like:

```
xml = open(url).read
```

Note you can always determine what something is by asking for its class:

```
open(url).class  # => Tempfile
```

Comment: many thanks! tryign to find a list of all the methods and how to use them... besides .read

Comment: `open(url).class # => StringIO`

Comment: @Odin, `require open-uri`